# How to keep remote of git subtree in repository?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-subtree

I have a repository where one directory is a subtree from somewhere else. I know I can add a remote in my local repository, but this gets lost when I push to another repository.

I would like to have knowledge of the subtree remote stored in the super repository. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the default merge message with -m to store the remote URL is the only option I could find.